# AngularJS directive not showing template but others working fine

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add another AngularJS directive to my app but for some reason it is not working. I have added other directives before in the same way but they are all working. I have posted code below.

HTML where I include the directive

```
<section class="section-wrap" data-ng-controller="PVProfileViewController">
<div class="container bg_white">
    <div>
        <pv-profile-password-reset pv-user="user"></pv-profile-password-reset>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pv-profile-email-update pv-user="user"></pv-profile-email-update>
    </div>

</div>


</section>
```

AngularJS directive file

'use strict';

```
/*
 * The profile email request update section
 */
angular.module('mean.system').directive('pvProfileEmailUpdate',
    ['PVProfile', '$timeout', 'Global', 'Utilities',
     function (PVProfile, $timeout, Global, Utilities)
     {
         function controller($scope)
         {
             $scope.global = Global;

             $scope.darkout = false;

         }


         function link(scope, element, attrs)
         {

         }

         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: '/path/to/profile_email_update.html',
             link: link,
             scope: {
                 user: '=pvUser'
             },
             controller: controller
         };
     }
    ]
);
```

Any ideas why this specific directive would not be working but others very similar to it would be?

Comment: possible reason would be the templateUrl is wrong. What browser are you using, if it's IE it could be the restrict

Comment: it's chrome and what do you mean the templateUrl? path is the exact same as the other directives similar to this one that are showing up fine

Comment: is there error in console?

Comment: or the templateUrl is protected and you don't have permission to load the html template

Comment: could you add whole html? looks like you placed directive element outside angular context

Comment: i have edited to show the whole HTML, the password reset template is working fine and is the one which I pretty much copy-pasted to use as an outline for my directive

Comment: and just checked, not a permission problem

Comment: are you including a script tag for your directive.js file in the html?

Comment: No but there is no script tag in the password_reset.html and it is still working fine

Comment: ok. but how is the application being made aware of your new directive?